# When I try to play a multiplayer game, I get the error "The server is not avaliable"?

Tags: splinter-cell-conviction

When I attempt to play a multi-player game in *Splinter Cell: Conviction*, I get the error "The Splinter Cell: conviction server is not avaliable at this time. Please try again later" on the title screen.

I have tried forwarding the ports that Ubisoft's official website says I need to forward in order to play multi-player, but that did not work. I have also tried validating the game files (via steam- I bought the game off Steam.), but nothing has come of that. Also, my game version is 1.4.

Can anyone help? Other threads on the internet don't seem to be much help with this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I've had this problem as well. It is caused by bad CD-keys that were sold via Steam. You need to contact [Ubisoft support](https://support.ubi.com/en-us/) and have them issue you a new CD-key. While you wait for them to issue your new CD-key, you could play using [Tunngle](http://www.tunngle.net/) (a number of people are generally available in the Conviction network).

Assuming they handle your case as they did mine, you will need to send them a screenshot of Steam confirming your purchase and a screenshot of your CD-key as shown in Steam, as well as your consent to revoke your current CD-key and issue you a new one. I recommend sending all of these things along with your first message, as they are notoriously slow to respond.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot say with complete certainty but I am pretty sure it is a DNS issue.
some sites in your browser work and some don't, some games work online and some don't.

I am having the same issue with my DNS.

Try updating your DNS to Google's DNS.

To do this, follow these steps:

1. go to "control panel"
2. click on "Network And Sharing Center"
3. click on "change adapter settings" to the left of the window
4. right-click on the adapter you are using and click on "properties".
5. double click "Internet protocol version 4(TCP/IPv4)"
6. make sure "Use the following DNS addresses" is ticked
7. enter "8.8.8.8" into the "Preferred DNS Server" box

You should be all set then, hope it works for you too.